# Search box web part query suggestion display

Tags: search, css, query-string, search-box

2 questions pertaining to the search box web part display:

1) I have configured the search box web part to show query suggestions. My issue is when I type for example "ca" I not only get suggestions that start with "ca" but also contains "ca".
suggestions displayed:
Jefferson Capital
Southern California
Capital One
Cavalry
How do I go about changing the query parameters to show suggestions that begin with...? In this example I would only want to display Capital One and Cavalry?

2) Also the query suggestions (`srch-AutoCompContainer`) is overlapping the search box web part. I can't seem to figure out how to move the container down to display the suggestions under the search box web part. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my 2nd question. I used f12 to figure out the css page being used. Located the class in SPD and made the following change:

.srch-AutoCompContainer 
     margin-top:22px;

But I am still looking for an answer to my first question.

Comment: say you don't have access to the css file, is there a way to get this to work via the content editor web part?